# Roll Counter Increment by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I need help on the script for the counter to increment by one and have a animation of the incremented number, slide to top

[image]

something like that on the picture and this is what I have done so far.

```css
        .booking-wrapper .countdown-wrapper .countdown-container .order-list {
        border: 5px solid #959595;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 1;
        height: 56px;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
    
    .booking-wrapper .countdown-wrapper .countdown-container .order-list .order-list-item {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="countdown-container">
             <ul id="order-list" class="order-list">
                 <li class="order-list-item"><span>0</span></li>
                 <li class="order-list-item" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"><span>0</span></li>
                 <li class="order-list-item" style="border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;"><span>8</span></li>
                 <li class="order-list-item"><span>1</span></li>
             </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: ["I need help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5459839) is not an actual question. Could you pinpoint what is the exact problem you are facing to complete the job?

Comment: this may probably help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596555/8620333

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use some existing library for that. But if you want to have your own implementation, then use the following elements:

- Use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), and in particular the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property and the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event.
- Build the inner HTML dynamically, so that in the original HTML you only have the container element, which will initially be empty.
- Let the HTML at the deepest level (for one digit) be 3 lines: on each line you put a digit. For example `8<br>9<br>0`. They should form a sequence. Scroll the middle digit into view so that only that digit is visible. Perform the animation upward or downward as needed, and when the animation is complete, update the HTML and reset the scroll offset (which can be the `top` CSS property).
- There is no need to have the `span` elements. Just put the content straight into the `li` elements.
- Use promises, which make asynchronous code look better, certainly when using `await`

So here is how you could do it:

```js
// Utility functions returning promises
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const nextFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
const animate = (elem, prop, value, duration) => {
    return nextFrame().then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
        elem.style.transition = `${prop} ${duration}ms`;
        elem.style[prop] = `${value}px`;
        const done = () => {
            elem.style.transition = `${prop} 0ms`;
            resolve();
        }
        elem.addEventListener("transitionend", done, {once: true});
    })).then(nextFrame);
};

// DOM element wrapper for the counter functionality
class Counter {
    constructor(element, length = 4, upwards = true) {
        this.element = element;
        this._value = 0;
        this.upwards = !!upwards;
        this.digits = Array.from({length}, () => element.appendChild(document.createElement("li")));
    }
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
        const numStr = value.toString().padStart(4, "0").slice(-this.digits.length);
        // Display the current number in the counter element (no animation)
        this.digits.forEach( (digit, i) => {
            // Put three lines, each having a digit, where the middle one is the current one:
            digit.innerHTML = `${(+numStr[i]+(this.upwards ? 9 : 1))%10}<br>${numStr[i]}<br>${(+numStr[i]+(this.upwards ? 1 : 9))%10}`;
            digit.style.top = `${-this.element.clientHeight}px`; // scroll the middle digit into view
        });
    }
    async roll(direction = 1, duration = 500) {
        await nextFrame();
        const numChangingDigits = Math.min(this.digits.length, 
            this.value.toString().length - this.value.toString().search(direction > 0 ? /9*$/ : /0*$/) + 1);
        const numStr = this.value.toString().padStart(4, "0").slice(-numChangingDigits);
        const promises = this.digits.slice(-numChangingDigits).map((digit, i) =>
            animate(digit, "top", (direction > 0) === this.upwards ? -this.element.clientHeight*2 : 0, duration)
        );
        await Promise.all(promises);
        this.value = this.value + direction;
        await nextFrame();
    }
    async rollTo(target, duration = 500, pause = 300) {
        const direction = Math.sign(target - this.value);
        while (this.value !== target) {
            await this.roll(direction, duration);
            await delay(pause);
        }
    }
}

// Demo:
const counter = new Counter(document.getElementById("order-list"), 4, true);
counter.value = 9931;
counter.rollTo(10002, 500, 300);
```

```css
.order-list {
    border: 5px solid #999;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.order-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.order-list > li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="order-list" class="order-list"></ul>
```

There are some arguments you can use to modify the speed of the animations. There is also an argument that determines whether the dials roll upward or downward for getting the next digit.

Answer (score 0):

just use odometerjs, it's a javascript library to add roll-counters with various themes.

https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/